# Arrange multiple TikZ pictures

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, formatting

Can anybody tell me how to arrange 5 TikZ pictures like this? I am very sorry, but I have no idea how to.

[image]

I uploaded the Codes and the png file [here](https://www.wetransfer.com/downloads/264f3b9ca062f4a67aea5f7feb5e038f20150731092151/b5de1f)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `scope` environment of Tikz is well suited for such tasks, as it allows to shift and rotate everything it contains. My suggestion is to create one `tikzpicture` and then create a different scope for each `axis` you have. This leads to a setup like this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{scope}
        \input{X}
    \end{scope}

    \begin{scope}[yshift=6cm]
        \input{G_1}
    \end{scope}

    \begin{scope}[yshift=8cm]
        \input{G_2}
    \end{scope}

    \begin{scope}[xshift=1cm,yshift=-0.8cm,rotate=90]
        \input{B_1}
    \end{scope}

    \begin{scope}[xshift=-2cm,yshift=-0.8cm,rotate=90]
        \input{B_2}
    \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Note: so far, every `.tex` file includes a `\begin{tikzpicture} ... \end{tikzpicture}`. For a solution like this here, you need to *remove* that, so only the `axis` stuff remains.

The result (shown below) might not be perfect, but by adjusting the shifts, you should be able to get a nice result.

[image: result]

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use a `tabular`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}‎‎

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{}cccc@{}}
& &  \input{G_1} \\
& &  \input{G_2} \\
\rotatebox{90}{\input{B_1}} & \rotatebox{90}{\input{B_2}} & \input{X} \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! The tikzpictures are too big. Is there an oppotiunity to include external tikz files into it?

Comment: @user2307200 That's a different issue, apparently. What exactly do you mean with the tikzpictures are too big? You can scale them down.

Comment: Do you have your `tikzpicture`s as standalone files? If so, you can use something like `\includegraphics[width=1cm,height=0.8cm]{figure1}` instead of `\rule` in my example (of course, `\usepackage{graphicx}` in the preamble).

Comment: Thanks, that works! But I need to rotate two of my tikz file (these on the left) and that breaks the arrangement :/  I used "\begin{rotate}{90}..."

Comment: I found a solution using  \hspace{20 mm} beteen the tikz-files. But now the vertical spaces are not equal and I do not want to use  \vspace{20 mm}... There must be a better solution, is it?

Comment: @user2307200 Instead of loosing time guessing possible solutions, can you upload elsewhere the images and tell me exactly how they should appear (you never mentined rotation before) so  we can give you the best alternative?

Comment: @user2307200 Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks very much! But the lower diagramms are not on an equal level with their upper border.